# C# CounterSample TimeStamp to DateTime

Tags: c#, timestamp, performancecounter

I have code that collects performance information from Windows and it seems the `TimeStamp` value in the `CounterSample` class does not make sense.

I have tried multiple options and it seems the closest I could get the `DateTime` calculation is to some date in 2013 which is clearly wrong.

The Class produces a `TimeStamp` "1377758421268" which seems to be in milliseconds but I'm not sure how to get this number to the correct `DateTime` format.

This is the function I use that does not work:

```
    public static DateTime ConvertTimeStamp(long TimeStamp)
    {
          DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
          epoch = epoch.AddMilliseconds(TimeStamp);
          return epoch;
    }
```

This is the output from the code:

```
9/7/2013 7:05:01 PM   LogicalDisk:Split IO/Sec:HarddiskVolume4 = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:04 PM   PhysicalDisk:Current Disk Queue Length:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:06 PM   PhysicalDisk:% Disk Time:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:08 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk Queue Length:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:10 PM   PhysicalDisk:% Disk Read Time:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:12 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk Read Queue Length:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:14 PM   PhysicalDisk:% Disk Write Time:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:16 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk Write Queue Length:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:18 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk sec/Transfer:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:19 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk sec/Read:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:20 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk sec/Write:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:21 PM   PhysicalDisk:Disk Transfers/sec:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:23 PM   PhysicalDisk:Disk Reads/sec:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:24 PM   PhysicalDisk:Disk Writes/sec:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:25 PM   PhysicalDisk:Disk Bytes/sec:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:26 PM   PhysicalDisk:Disk Read Bytes/sec:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:27 PM   PhysicalDisk:Disk Write Bytes/sec:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:28 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk Bytes/Transfer:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:30 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk Bytes/Read:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:31 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk Bytes/Write:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:32 PM   PhysicalDisk:% Idle Time:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:34 PM   PhysicalDisk:Split IO/Sec:0 C: = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:36 PM   PhysicalDisk:Current Disk Queue Length:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:37 PM   PhysicalDisk:% Disk Time:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:39 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk Queue Length:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:40 PM   PhysicalDisk:% Disk Read Time:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:42 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk Read Queue Length:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:43 PM   PhysicalDisk:% Disk Write Time:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:45 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk Write Queue Length:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:47 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk sec/Transfer:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:48 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk sec/Read:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:50 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk sec/Write:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:52 PM   PhysicalDisk:Disk Transfers/sec:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:54 PM   PhysicalDisk:Disk Reads/sec:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:55 PM   PhysicalDisk:Disk Writes/sec:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:56 PM   PhysicalDisk:Disk Bytes/sec:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:58 PM   PhysicalDisk:Disk Read Bytes/sec:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:05:59 PM   PhysicalDisk:Disk Write Bytes/sec:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:06:00 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk Bytes/Transfer:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:06:01 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk Bytes/Read:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:06:02 PM   PhysicalDisk:Avg. Disk Bytes/Write:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:06:03 PM   PhysicalDisk:% Idle Time:_Total = 0
9/7/2013 7:06:05 PM   PhysicalDisk:Split IO/Sec:_Total = 0
```

Comment: `PerformaceCounter` does not have a time stamp.  What are using to get the time stamp?

Comment: Very true. Its from the CounterSample interface. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.countersample(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Anybody knows how to convert the TimeStamp variable in CounterSample to a DateTime format?